# Problem using TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

When I do as follows:

```
$html = '<div style="color: red; border: solid 2px blue; width: 100px; height: 200px;">Hello World!</div>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, true);
```

I get the following div:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA4Fn.jpg

It is not `width: 100px; height: 200px;` as you can see in the image. Why does my style not work properly?

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute measurement such as `cm` or `mm` instead of pixels? (i.e.: `height:2cm;`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is presumably because TCPDF doesn't support precise HTML to PDF conversion for every CSS style element/unit of measure.

You could try opening a bug over on the project's [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=128076&atid=710532) page, if this issue isn't already covered.

Answer (score 0):

Limur

Tcpdf does not support width and height css property to make pdf file best solution is that plase place a particular image instead of setting width height.